# Cyclic inheritance uses

Tags: java, inheritance

So if I write the following code in Java:

```
public class A extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

This gives a compiler error message    cyclic inheritance involving A.

The same happens if I write two classes A and B and A inherits B and B inherits A.

This makes sense to me, as it is quite hard to imagine how this would be possible anyway.

I then asked about this from one of the professors at my uni. He said there are languages where this is possible and he lamented how this is not possible in Java and that he had done some projects where he had used cyclic inheritance and so on, but I couldn't really understand any of it. He also mentioned he had had problems where he would have liked to use cyclic inheritance.

Can you educate me on the possible uses of this strange phenomena of cyclic inheritance? When is it possible and how? Are there problems where this could be useful?

Comment: It would be better if you ask your **teacher** to **teach** you. A teacher's labor can't be confusing the students and let them without a concrete answer.

Comment: A thing to keep in mind is that people in academia can sometimes lack practical thinking when it comes to some of their pet ideas, especially as they get older. I had an instructor that thought the best way to design linked lists was to make clients inherit from the `ListNode` class, because that's how the Modula-3 environment the heyday of his academic career was based in did things. (Even if this would be an obvious design abomination to most anyone else.) If you can't think of a use for an exotic language construct, and the professor can't explain it simply, maybe it's just not very useful.

Comment: Now that I think of it, he might have said he simulated this type of inheritance or something, not use it as is, but not sure. This all happened some years ago...

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I asked this in a corridor or something and he didn't have too much time and all...

Comment: Some years ago I came across a language in which `True` and `False` were distinct classes and were defined mutually recursively. Sadly I forget the name of the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dug up this [interesting reference](http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/cecil/www/Vortex-Three-Zero/doc-cecil-lang/cecil-spec-46.html): basically it says that cyclic inheritance is valid as long as there are no repeated fields, as the lookup for any field just needs to traverse one loop of the cycle to find out a meaning. If a field is repeated then none of the two definitions is more valid than the other and apparently there would be a problem.

So suppose that you want to define a person as a human and as a voter, and set different attributes for each. In pseudo-code:

```
class Person extends Human:
  String name;

class Human extends Voter:
  String language;

class Voter extends Person:
  Country residence;
```

Now you can address different aspects of an individual without having to define a hierarchy, and you might instantiate different people as a Person (with name), a Human (that speaks a language) or a Voter (in a particular country). No aspect is more important than the other.

While interesting, I don't think it is practical to use outside of research projects. Imagine having constructors for all classes that pass parameters to the super() constructors -- it would be easy to mess up the whole construct.

Update: the given pseudocode does not compile when translated to Java 8, and apparently under any language (except Cecil as shown by the link given above). It seems that nobody found any valid uses and therefore disallowed cyclic inheritance. This does not mean that the concept is inherently impossible; just that the practical uses do not justify the effort implementing the special case.

Comment: `If a field is repeated then none of the two definitions is more valid than the other and apparently there would be a problem.` - Why? If we have: `class A extends B: String field1; class B extends A: String field1` then if we make an instance `a = A.new('field1 in A')` then `a.field1` will call `field1` from `A`. ps. there might be a problem that cause an infinite loop: if `field1` is a procedure/function (a.field1 call b.field1 => b.field1 call a.field1 => ... the infinite loop)

Comment: @alexfernandez I ran this code, and got an compiler error.

Comment: It is, after all, pseudo-code. You need to translate it to your programming language of choice.

Comment: This doesn't compile, and the link you gave is to a completely different language. Theoretically cyclic dependencies are possible, but that doesn't mean that all languages allow them.

Also, the phrasing of your response is hard to follow and doesn't match the pseudocode that you give. "...suppose you want to define a Person as a Human and as a Voter" suggests "Person extends Human, Voter".

I know this is 5 years after this was posted, but an edit should be in order since it is the first thing I found on my Google search (and is accepted).

On the up side, learned about a new language!

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify that the code does not compile in Java. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Awesome, multiplied my downvote by -1. I will return when I have found a valid use case where cyclic inheritance is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I could only see it possible if the classes were on the same level of hierarchy. Think of the class hierarchy as a tree, which it is. Java looks for the hierarchy to be at least one level above or more. In some languages, you would be able to inherit characteristics from a class on the same level as the class you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the sense of cyclic inheritance. I don't know why your professor thinks it's useful in anycase mind that the inheritance reation that is called **IS-A** relationship states that if B is a subclass of A then B IS-A A in the sense that everywhere an A is required then a B can be used without problem (*Liskov substitution principle*).

Now, theoretically, if A is a subclass of B and B is a subclass of A then then both classes must have exactly the same outside interface. This because if you add a method to any of them the other one will inherit the same method automatically so you will have either to override it either to get the other implementation.

In addition you will have many circumstanced in which odd side effects comes into play (think about method `A.foo()` calling `super.foo()` and `B.foo()` calling `super.foo()`. I don't see any practical reason because this should be allowed.

Inheritance is intended as a tree in which every subclass specifies the behavior or the classes that are up in the tree, having two classes at the same level doesn't mean anything useful.

Comment: Things are not always meant to be used as intended...But I get your point, that's what I think too, but I still would be interested if there are some kind of, more theoretical or mathematical, applications to such an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the accepted answer that states that their code will not throw an error. I am running Java 8 and compiled the following code:

```
class Person extends Human:
  String name;
class Human extends Voter:
  String language;
class Voter extends Person:
  String residence;
```

and I recieved an error stating "error: cyclic inheritance involving Person."

Therefore, in Java you can not have cyclic inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

**Cyclic inheritance** is of no use and moreover let us see why logically it is not allowed.

I would like to start with `Object` class, if a class doesn't extend any class it extends `Object` class (this is true), and if a class extends any other class indirectly extends the `Object` class.

**Example:**

```
class B
{
..//
}
class A extends B
{
...//
}
```

class `A` extends `Object`, because `B` class extends `Object` class.

So when we do **Cyclic Inheritance**, it never extended the Object class.

**Example:**

```
class A extends A
{
}
```

I hope I was clear, so and a class that cannot extend `Object` class that is not possible in Java.

Comment: This answer only says that cyclic inheritance requires multiple inheritance.